# Lodash - Optional Memoize

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is it possible to avoid getting results from cache when calling a function wrapped in `lodash _.memoize()`?

For example

```
import { memoize } from "lodash";

export const getUserPost = memoize(
  async (userId, postId) => {
    const postRef = firestore
      .collection("posts")
      .doc(userId)
      .collection("userPosts")
      .doc(postId);

    const postDoc = await postRef.get();
   
    ...

    return parseUserPost(postDoc);
  },
  (userId, postId) => `[${userId},${postId}]`
);
```

If I call `getUserPost("raul", "postId")` I will always be getting cached result if they are in cache...

Is it possible to use the `memoize` method with some kind of argument to get from the server instead?

Something like

```
getUserPost("raul", "postId", { cached: false });
```

Comment: If not, could it be possible to add some kind of ttl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `_.memoize()` uses the 1st parameter (`userId` in your case) as the key in in the memoization cache, or it uses a resolver, like the on you supplied:

```
(userId, postId) =>`[${userId},${postId}]`
```

You can delete that key from the cache, when you don't want to a specific value to return the same result:

Example:

```js
const fn = _.memoize(x => x + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000))

console.log(fn(1))
console.log(fn(1))
fn.cache.delete(1) // remove a paremter from the cache
console.log(fn(1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```